# Let d3.scaleLinear() be "upside down"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When drawing a chart with svg, typically the y axis/scale needs to be "flipped":

- In svg space, zero is at the top left, the higher x and y values are towards the bottom right.
- In a typical domain coordinate system, zero is at the bottom left, the higher x and y values are towards the top right.

With d3.scaleLinear() I am aware of two ways to do this:

- Flip the domain: `var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([vx1, vx0]).range([0, 400]);`
- Flip the range: `var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([vx0, vx1]).range([400, 0]);`

Both of these methods seem kinda suboptimal. If I want to do further calculations with the range or the domain, it is often advantageous to have the smaller value at domain[0] / range[0], and the higher value at domain[1] / range[1]. Having one of them flipped can cause confusion.

Which of the two methods is more common or recommended? Or is there a third way, where the scale itself does the flipping, but both range and domain have the "correct" order?

Comment: You can always map the domain to a negative range as well [-400, 0]

Answer (score 1):

I would always do the `.range()` upside down, as it's more true. The aim behind the scale is to translate the input data range to the output pixel range. In this case the data range is as you would expect, but the pixel co-ordinates are inverted - hence inverting the range.

Comment: Sounds sensible. I think I had to hear it from someone other than myself :)